# Unable to delete row in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want when the `timing` date in CodeIgniter is less than current date then it should delete the row auto.
I have a table named `doctor` . The fields are `id(int)`, `crated_at(timestamp)` `timings(varchar)`, `name(varchar)`.

I use to insert the timing in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. I want when the date is less than the current date then is should delete the row auto.

**MODEL**

```
public function delete_book(){
    $date  = date("m/d/Y");
    $this->db->where("timings < (".$date." - INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
    $this->db->delete("doctors");

}
```

Please let me know about the fault of my code

Comment: use datetime data type in timings. Or you can sue date data type.

Comment: actually i'm inserting date from datapicker in html form so is it possible to do so?

Comment: yes possible, just change date formate according to your need when you insert.

Comment: let me change and i'll let u know

Comment: I've changed that to `date` and entered the date `2018-09-22` but the code isn't working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$this->db->where("timings < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)",NULL,FALSE);
$this->db->delete("doctors");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NOW()` function of MySql. `NOW()` returns the date of the system and it is also compatible with MySql query.

```
public function delete_book(){
    //$date  = date("m/d/Y");
    $this->db->where("timings < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
    $this->db->delete("doctors");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will work may use

```
$this->db->where('timings BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW()', "", false);
$this->db->delete("doctors");
```

Hope fully works.

Answer (score -1):

You may use [DATE_SUB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function

```
public function delete_book(){
    $this->db->where("timings < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
    $this->db->delete("doctors");

}
```

above function produced query is :-

```
DELETE FROM `doctors` WHERE `timings` < DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: @Codecraker type of timings to date ? yes you should.

Comment: But i've changed the type `varchar` to `date` but not happeing . he date is currently inserted is `2018-09-22`

Comment: @Codecraker i have added the generated sql in answer and its fine.

Comment: Put the same in sql it's working but not from codeigniter framework